# Syntax errors in pizza order program

Tags: java

Can anybody help me with this?
simple pizza order program
I tried to run it in commandpromt and there are a lot of error
I have tried to change the double into int.. but the result is still error

```
<pre>
public class PizzaOrder
{
public static final String PIZZA_SMALL = "S";
public static final String PIZZA_MEDIUM = "M";
public static final String PIZZA_LARGE = "L";
public static final String PIZZA_COLLOSAL = "C";

public static final double SMALL_DIAMETER = 9;
public static final double MEIDUM_DIAMETER = 13;
public static final double LARGE_DIAMETER = 17;
public static final double COLOSSAL_DIAMETER = 26;

public static final double PRICE_SMALL = 8;
public static final double PRICE_MEDIUM = 11;
public static final double PRICE_LARGE = 15;
public static final double PRICE_COLOSSAL = 21;
public static final double PRICE_TAX = 0.095;
public static final double PRICE_TOPPING = 0.99;

public static final int MAX_TOPPINGS = 8;
public static final int MIN_TOPPINGS = 0;

/**
 * Pizza Order
 *
 * @param args command-line arguments
 */

public static int getDiameter(String pizzaName)
{
    if (pizzaName.equals(PIZZA_SMALL))
    {
        return SMALL_DIAMETER;
    }
    else if (pizzaName.equals(PIZZA_MEIDUM))
    {
        return MEDIUM_DIAMETER;
    }`enter code here`
    else if (pizzaName.equals(PIZZA_LARGE))
    {
        return LARGE_DIAMETER;
    }
    else
    {
        return COLOSSAL_DIAMETER;
    }
}

public static int getBasePrice(String pizzaName)
{
    if (pizzaName.equals(PIZZA_SMALL))
    {
        return PRICE_SMALL;
    }
    else if (pizzaName.equals(PIZZA_MEIDUM))
    {
        return PRICE_MEDIUM;
    }
    else if (pizzaName.equals(PIZZA_LARGE))
    {
        return PRICE_LARGE;
    }
    else
    {
        return PRICE_COLOSSAL;
    }
}
```

there are error about the scanner too idk why
there are 13-20 errors and mostly because of the variables PIZZA_SMALL, etc
some errors say "incompetible types" and the other says "cannot find symbol"

`public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter The Size of Pizza you" 
    + "want: (S/M/L/C)");
    String option = keyboard.nextLine().trim().substring(0,          
    1).toUppercase();


    double pizzaPrice;
    double pizzaSize;


    if(option.equals(PIZZA_SMALL))
    {
        pizzaPrice = SMALL_DIAMETER;
        pizzaSize = SMALL_DIAMETER;
    }
    else if (option.equals(PIZZA_MEIDUM))
    {
        pizzaPrice = PRICE_MEDIUM;
        pizzaSize = MEDIUM_DIAMETER;
    }
    else if (option.equals(PIZZA_LARGE))
    {
        pizzaPrice = PRICE_LARGE;
        pizzaSize = LARGE_DIAMETER;
    }
    else
    {
        option = PIZZA_COLOSSAL;            
        pizzaPrice = PRICE_COLOSSAL;
        pizzaSize = COLOSSAL_DIAMETER;
    }


    System.out.println("Pizza Size: " + option);
    System.out.println("Enter The Number of Toppings" +
    "you want:(0-8)");

    int pizzaTopping = keyboard.nextInt();      

    if(pizzaTopping < MIN_TOPPINGS)
    {
        pizzaTopping = MIN_TOPPINGS;
    }
    else if(pizzaTopping > MAX_TOPPINGS)
    {
        pizzaTopping = MAX_TOPPINGS;
    }
    else    
    {
        pizzaTopping = pizzaTopping;
    }


    int radius = getDiameter(option) / 2;
    double squareInches = radius * radius * Math.PI;
    System.out.println("Pizza Size: " + option + "( " + pizzaSize + 
    "inch -- " + squareInches + " square inches)" );

    System.out.println("Toppings: " + pizzaTopping);

    double priceWithToppings = getBasePrice(option) + pizzaTopping * 9;
    System.out.println("Price: " + priceWithToppings);  

    double pizzaTax = priceWithToppings * PRICE_TAX;
    System.out.println("Tax: "+ pizzaTax);

    double totalPrice = priceWithToppings + pizzaTax;
    System.out.println("Total Price: " + totalPrice);

    double priceEachSquareInch = priceWithToppings / squareInches;
    System.out.println("Price/sq.in.: " + priceEachSquareInch);

    }
 }`

Comment: One of your problems is in getDiameter you return a double value for a method that says it returns int. Additionally, consider doing some work to figure out what's wrong. Then point out specifically what's the matter with it (don't just say it doesn't work).

Comment: Thankyou for your help... im a beginner this is my first program after hello world

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `PizzaOrder` class should be as follows:

```
public class PizzaOrder {
    public static final String PIZZA_SMALL = "S";
    public static final String PIZZA_MEDIUM = "M";
    public static final String PIZZA_LARGE = "L";
    public static final String PIZZA_COLLOSAL = "C";

    public static final double SMALL_DIAMETER = 9;
    public static final double MEDIUM_DIAMETER = 13;
    public static final double LARGE_DIAMETER = 17;
    public static final double COLOSSAL_DIAMETER = 26;

    public static final double PRICE_SMALL = 8;
    public static final double PRICE_MEDIUM = 11;
    public static final double PRICE_LARGE = 15;
    public static final double PRICE_COLOSSAL = 21;
    public static final double PRICE_TAX = 0.095;
    public static final double PRICE_TOPPING = 0.99;

    public static final int MAX_TOPPINGS = 8;
    public static final int MIN_TOPPINGS = 0;

    /**
     * Pizza Order
     *
     * @param args
     *            command-line arguments
     */

    public static double getDiameter(String pizzaName) {
        if (pizzaName.equals(PIZZA_SMALL)) {
            return SMALL_DIAMETER;
        } else if (pizzaName.equals(PIZZA_MEDIUM)) {
            return MEDIUM_DIAMETER;
        } else if (pizzaName.equals(PIZZA_LARGE)) {
            return LARGE_DIAMETER;
        } else {
            return COLOSSAL_DIAMETER;
        }
    }

    public static double getBasePrice(String pizzaName) {
        if (pizzaName.equals(PIZZA_SMALL)) {
            return PRICE_SMALL;
        } else if (pizzaName.equals(PIZZA_MEDIUM)) {
            return PRICE_MEDIUM;
        } else if (pizzaName.equals(PIZZA_LARGE)) {
            return PRICE_LARGE;
        } else {
            return PRICE_COLOSSAL;
        }
    }
}
```

Notice how I corrected the return type from `int` to `double` on `getDiameter` and `getBasePrice`, as the constants you are trying to return are double. I also fixed the misspelling of "Medium" in some places.

To fix the scanner error, you must import it's package using: (Add this at the top of the file)

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

You `main` method should look like this: (Again, misspelling variables and casting errors)

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter The Size of Pizza you" + "want: (S/M/L/C)");
    String option = keyboard.nextLine().trim().substring(0,1).toUpperCase();

    double pizzaPrice;
    double pizzaSize;

    if(option.equals(PIZZA_SMALL))
    {
        pizzaPrice = SMALL_DIAMETER;
        pizzaSize = SMALL_DIAMETER;
    }
    else if (option.equals(PIZZA_MEDIUM))
    {
        pizzaPrice = PRICE_MEDIUM;
        pizzaSize = MEDIUM_DIAMETER;
    }
    else if (option.equals(PIZZA_LARGE))
    {
        pizzaPrice = PRICE_LARGE;
        pizzaSize = LARGE_DIAMETER;
    }
    else
    {
        option = PIZZA_COLLOSAL;            
        pizzaPrice = PRICE_COLOSSAL;
        pizzaSize = COLOSSAL_DIAMETER;
    }


    System.out.println("Pizza Size: " + option);
    System.out.println("Enter The Number of Toppings" +
    "you want:(0-8)");

    int pizzaTopping = keyboard.nextInt();      

    if(pizzaTopping < MIN_TOPPINGS)
    {
        pizzaTopping = MIN_TOPPINGS;
    }
    else if(pizzaTopping > MAX_TOPPINGS)
    {
        pizzaTopping = MAX_TOPPINGS;
    }

    double radius = getDiameter(option) / 2;
    double squareInches = radius * radius * Math.PI;
    System.out.println("Pizza Size: " + option + "( " + pizzaSize + 
    "inch -- " + squareInches + " square inches)" );

    System.out.println("Toppings: " + pizzaTopping);

    double priceWithToppings = getBasePrice(option) + pizzaTopping * 9;
    System.out.println("Price: " + priceWithToppings);  

    double pizzaTax = priceWithToppings * PRICE_TAX;
    System.out.println("Tax: "+ pizzaTax);

    double totalPrice = priceWithToppings + pizzaTax;
    System.out.println("Total Price: " + totalPrice);

    double priceEachSquareInch = priceWithToppings / squareInches;
    System.out.println("Price/sq.in.: " + priceEachSquareInch);

    }
 }
```

If you want to cast a `double` to an `int`, you need to do `int something = (int)myDouble`. Also pay attention when writing your variable names, as they must be exactly the same as the definition or they will throw an error. Also, if a method returns an `int`, but you try and return a `double`, it will result in an error, as the return type must be the same as what is defined in the method.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, take a good look through your code as many of your errors are typos - e.g. toUppercase(), COLLOSAL etc.

And, as per Ben's comment you are using doubles for your constants but then your methods are all integers.   Java won't let you do this automatically as it results everything after the decimal point being lost as integers are whole numbers only.

When these two things are changed your code appears to work - at a quick glimpse at least.